# When debugging in Visual Studio I get message 'Access is denied' in the browser with Local IIS Server NOT with IIS EXPRESS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, iis, iis-express

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 solution right now. When I press F5 (Start Debugging) in Visual Studio 2012, Internet Explorer is opening and I can see `Access is denied.` (see below) in the tab title. After a few seconds, I access to the first page as intended.

In Visual Studio: If I switch from IE to GC (dropdown choice) and start debugging, I don't get this message.

Any idea why I got this message?

[image]

---

UPDATE: I noticed that

- when checking `Use IIS EXPRESS` the problem disappear.
- when unchecking `Use IIS EXPRESS` (so using IIS Web Server) the problem is here again.

Maybe an authorization right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of things as suggested in others posts, finally I had to delete temporary Internet Explorer files. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a result of  [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894433)  documented Internet Explorer bug, which occurs  because the ASP.NET worker process does not have the *Impersonate a client after authentication* user right.

Comment: The document explains the problem when using Win XP. I'm using Win 8. Furthermore, I have another ASP.NET MVC website which is nearly the same website which didn't reproduce the problem mentioned.

Comment: Interesting. I'm presuming that under your project properties in Visual Studio, Windows Authentication is enabled?

Comment: I don't have `Windows Authentication` property on my project properties. But I added additional informations in my question, please take a look.